# Union ip address and port (regexp)

Tags: php, regex

I have a string line a `2h 2m   202.29.216.236      3128    flag Thailand`

```
$string = preg_replace("/([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})|(\s+\d{2,4}\s+)/", "$1:$2", $string);
```

I need to get the ip address like this: 202.29.216.236:3128.

But my code does this: `109.197.92.60:: 8080`.

I don't understand where did the space bar and two colons.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Because you have `\s` in your capture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$string = preg_replace("/([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\s+(\d{2,4})/", "$1:$2", $string);
```

The space comes from the **\s+** being inside the second param, and the second colon from the | char.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you make use of [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) ?

```
<?php
$str="2h 2m 202.29.216.236 3128 flag Thailand";
$str=explode(' ',$str);
echo $str[2].":".$str[3];//202.29.216.236:3128
```